# One-one correspondence between 2-Cohomology Group and (Equivalent) Abelian extension of Lie Algebra.

Tags: lie-algebras, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

One-one correspondence between 2-Cohomology Group and (Equivalent) Abelian extension of Lie Algebra.

> Sorry about any ambiguation, because I'm not familiar with homological algebra and category theory.
>
> And any corrections or clarifications are grateful.

We have **Chevalley-Eilenberg Complex**, and we can use this complex to calculate cohomology group (or $\mathbb{F}$-vector space) of it.

An application of  Chevalley-Eilenberg Complex is about **Abelian extension** of a given lie algebra.

So here is one-one correspondence between 2-Cohomology Group and (Equivalent) Abelian extension of Lie Algebra.

(I have a question about the proof of the theorem below)

> **Theorem** Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional representation of $\mathfrak{g}$. Regard $V$ as an abelian
> Lie algebra. Then there exists a bijection between $H^2(\mathfrak{g}, V )$ and the set of equivalence classes of abelian extensions of $\mathfrak{g}$ by $V$.
>
> **Remark**
>
> 1.Set $\mathcal{C}^q=\mathcal{C}^q(\mathfrak{g},V):=\operatorname{Hom}_F(\bigwedge^q\mathfrak{g},V)=(\bigwedge^q\mathfrak{g})^*\otimes V, q\ge 0$, And the **Chevalley-Eilenberg Complex** is $C^0\xrightarrow[]{d} C^1\xrightarrow[]{d}C^2\xrightarrow[]{d}C^3\xrightarrow[]{d}\dots$, $\mathrm{H}^q(\mathfrak{g},V):=\mathrm{ker}(d:\mathcal{C}^q\to\mathcal{C}^{q+1})/\mathrm{im}(d:\mathcal{C}^{q-1}\to\mathcal{C}^q).$
>
> 2.The exact sequence $0\to V\to\mathfrak{h}\to\mathfrak{g}\to0$ is called **Abelian extension** of $\mathfrak{g}$ by $V$, if all arrows are lie algebra homomorphism, and $V$ is an abelian lie algebra.
>
> 3.The **equivalent extensions** means that, there exist a commutative diagram:
> $$
> \begin{matrix}0&\longrightarrow&\mathfrak{a}&\longrightarrow&\mathfrak{g}&\longrightarrow&\mathfrak{b}&\longrightarrow&0\\ =\downarrow&&=\downarrow&&\varphi\downarrow&&=\downarrow& &=\downarrow\\ 0&\longrightarrow&\mathfrak{a}&\longrightarrow&\mathfrak{h}&\longrightarrow&\mathfrak{b}&\longrightarrow&0\end{matrix}
> $$
> And $\varphi:\mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{h}$ is a lie algebra isomorphism.

Let me state the proof briefly.

> Step1: prove the **Lemma 1**
>
> The exact sequence (of lie algebra) $0\rightarrow\mathfrak{a}\rightarrow\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow\mathfrak{b}\rightarrow0$ splits iff $\mathfrak{g}\simeq\mathfrak{b}\ltimes_{\pi}\mathfrak{a}$.
>
> **Remark**
>
> $\mathfrak{b}\ltimes_{\pi}\mathfrak{a}$ is a lie algebra, with underlying set $\mathfrak{b}\times\mathfrak{a}$ and the lie bracket defined as
> $$
> [(B_1,A_1),(B_2,A_2)]:=([B_1,B_2],\pi(B_1)A_2-\pi(B_2)A_1+[A_1,A_2]),\ A_1,A_2\in\mathfrak{a}, B_1,B_2\in\mathfrak{b}
> $$
>
> And $\pi:\mathfrak{b}\to \text{Der}_\mathbb{F}\mathfrak\ {a}$.

> Step2:  prove the **Lemma 2**
>
> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional representation of $\mathfrak{g}$. Then for any 2-cocycle $\omega$, define a bilinear map on the vector space $\mathfrak{h}:= \mathfrak{g}\oplus V$ .
> $$
>  [(X,v),(Y,u)]:=([X,Y],Xu-Yv+\omega(X,Y)).
>  $$
> The above bilinear map is indeed a Lie bracket, i.e, it is skew-symmetric and satisfies Jacobi identity.
> We write $\mathfrak{h}_{\omega}=\mathfrak{g}\oplus_{\omega}V$ for this Lie algebra. Hence
> $$
>  0\rightarrow V\rightarrow\mathfrak h_{\omega}\rightarrow\mathfrak g\rightarrow0
>  $$
> is an Abelian extension of $\mathfrak{g}$ by $V$.

> Step3:  prove **Lemma 3: the converse part of Lemma 2**
>
> Suppose that we have an abelian extension of Lie algebra
> $$
>  0\to V\xrightarrow{\iota}\mathfrak{h}\xrightarrow{\pi}\mathfrak{g}\to0.
>  $$
> The above exact sequence splits in the category of vector spaces, hence we can choose a section $s:\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow\mathfrak{h}$ (a linear map such that $\pi\circ s=\mathrm{Id}_{\mathfrak{g}}$).
>
> Define a linear map $\rho:\mathfrak{g}\to\operatorname{End}_{F}(V)$ via $\rho_{s}(X)(v):=[s(X),\iota(v)]$. This map is well-defined (i.e. independent of the choice of $s$).
> Thus, $\rho:\mathfrak{g}\to\operatorname{End}_{F}(V)$  is a representation of $\mathfrak{g}$ on $V$ (which can be checked easily by Jacobi identity). In this way, any abelian extension:
> $$
>  0\to V\xrightarrow{\iota}\mathfrak{h}\xrightarrow{\pi}\mathfrak{g}\to0.
>  $$
> naturally provides a $\mathfrak{g}$-module $V$ . Then it makes sense to discuss $\mathrm{~H}^{\ast}(\mathfrak{g},V)$.
>
> We identify $V$ with the subspace $\iota(V)$ in $\mathfrak{g}$. Take an arbitrary section $s:\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow\mathfrak{h}$, Define a function
> $$
>  \omega_s:\mathfrak{g}\times\mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{h},\ \omega_s(X,Y):=s([X,Y])-[s(X),s(Y)].
>  $$
> Then $\mathrm{Im}\omega_{s}\subseteq\operatorname{ker}\pi=V$ . Thus $\omega_s:\mathfrak{g}\times\mathfrak{g}\to V$. And (**Lemma 3**) $\omega_s$ is a is a 2-cocycle.

And here is my **Question1**:

In the **Theorem** above, $V$ is already a representation of $\mathfrak{g}$, which means the representation map $\mathfrak{g}\to \text{End}_\mathbb{F}V$ is given and fixed.

But in **Lemma 3**, given an Abelian extension, the exact sequence  $0\to V\xrightarrow{\iota}\mathfrak{h}\xrightarrow{\pi}\mathfrak{g}\to0$ itself provides another representation of $V$ on $\mathfrak{g}$. In other word, it may be different from the original one.

---

And we continue the (outline) of proof.

> Step4: prove the **Lemma 4**
>
> Let
> $$
> 0\to V\xrightarrow{\iota}\mathfrak{h}\xrightarrow{\pi}\mathfrak{g}\to0.
> $$
> be an abelian extension (And this exact sequence also provides a $\mathfrak{g}$-module $V$). Take $s : \mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{h}\simeq (\mathfrak{g}\ltimes V), X\mapsto(X, 0)$ and construct $\omega_s$ as in **Lemma 3**.
> Then the identity map on the vector space $\mathfrak{g}\ltimes V\simeq \mathfrak{h}_{\omega_s}$ is a Lie algebra isomorphism (And equivalence extension).

> Step5: prove the **Lemma 5**
>
> Let $s,s^{\prime}:\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow\mathfrak{h}$ be two sections. Construct $\omega_{s'}$ and $\omega_s$ as in **Lemma 3**.
> Then they are cohomological, i.e. they define the same cohomology class in $H^2(\mathfrak{g}, V )$.
>
> And $\mathfrak{h}_{\omega_s},\mathfrak{h}_{\omega_s'}$ are **equivalent extension**.

> Step6: prove the **Lemma 6**
>
> Let $\alpha$ be a 2-cocycle. Construct $\mathfrak{h}_\alpha$ as in **Lemma 2**. Then $\alpha$ can be recovered from the section $s : \mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{h}_\alpha, X\mapsto(X, 0)$.
> In other words, $\alpha(X,Y)=[s(X),s(Y)]-s([X,Y]).$

> Step7:
>
> **Lemma 2** says that we can construct an abelian extension $\mathfrak{h}_\alpha$ out of a 2-cocycle $\alpha$ .
>
> **Lemma 3** we can construct 2-cocycles from any abelian extension (such as $\mathfrak{h}_\alpha$).
>
> **Lemma 4** and **Lemma 6** implies that these two process are inverse to each other.
>
> **Lemma 5** The construction of 2-cocycle from Lie algebra extension depends on the choice of the section $s : \mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{h}$. Yet two different choices of the section yields the same cohomology class (Note in **Lemma 3** the representation of $\mathfrak{g} $ on $V$ is induced by abelian extension) as well as the same equivalence class of the extension. This finishes the proof of the **Theorem**.

(I'm confused with this proof, mainly because the **Question1** above)

And I think because in **Lemma 3** we can't fix the representation of $\mathfrak{g}$ on $V$, so the one-one correspondence should be
$$
\{\text{All abelian extension of}\ \mathfrak{g}\ \text{by}\ V\}\\
\stackrel{\mathrm{1:1}}{\longleftrightarrow}\\
\bigsqcup_{\text{All representation of $\mathfrak{g}$ on $V$, each of them induce one Chevalley-Eilenberg Complex}}\text{H}^2(\mathfrak{g},V_{\text{fixed representation}})
$$
But I think it is not the right answer either, because there is another question below.

---

**Question2** There is an example

Consider Abelian extension of $\mathbb{R}^2$(as abelian lie algebra) by $\mathbb{R}$.

There will be a split extension $0\to\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^2\to0$ ($\mathbb{R}^3$ is abelian lie algebra), and a  unique non-split extension  $0\to\mathbb{R}\to\mathfrak{h}_1\to\mathbb{R}^2\to0$, here $\mathfrak{h}_1$ is Heisenberg Lie algebra.

But $\text{H}^2(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}$ (Regard $\mathbb{R}$ as a trivial $\mathbb{R}^2$-module), which means there are infinitely many ($\text{card}(\mathbb{R})$) equivalence class of abelian extension of  of $\mathbb{R}^2$ by $\mathbb{R}$. But we have shown there are only 2 equivalence class.

---

Thank you for finishing reading this super long and verbose question.

And thanks in advance if you can give me some hint, correction or reference!

Answer (score 1):

I watched [http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/210BPage/handouts/Cohomology&Extensions.pdf](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/210BPage/handouts/Cohomology&Extensions.pdf) today, and all questions are solved.

**To Question1.**

The action of $\mathfrak{g}$ on $V$ must be a fixed one.

Which means, we need to state the 1:1 correspondence theorem as below:

$$
\{\text{Abelian Extension inducing the given}\ \mathfrak{g}-\text{module}\ V\}
\leftrightarrow H^2(\mathfrak{g},V)
$$

**To Question2.**

There are some automorphism $\varphi$ of Heisenberg Lie Algebra itself, that cannot be inserted into the (commutative) diagram (of equivalence Abelian Extension).

Regrading the underlying set of Heisenberg Lie Algebra $\mathfrak{h}_1$ as $(\mathfrak{g}=\mathbb{R}^2)\times\mathbb{R}$.

Since $\mathfrak{g}$ acts on $\mathbb{R}$ trivially, so the lie bracket is defined as.

$$
[(X,a),(Y,b)] = ([X,Y],\omega(X,Y))
$$

All nonzero 2-cocycle are linearly dependent ($H^2(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}$), so the lie brackets in all generated Lie Algebra $\mathfrak{h}_1^r$ should be.

$$
\text{in}\ \mathfrak{h}_1^r:\ [(X,a),(Y,b)] = ([X,Y],r\omega(X,Y)),\ r\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}
$$

All $\mathfrak{h}_1^r$ are isomorphic as Lie Algrbra.

Because we have $\varphi_r:\mathfrak{h}_1\to\mathfrak{h}_1^r $

$$
\varphi_r((X,a)) = (X, ra)
$$

But the following diagram is not commute (for the 2nd cube from the left).

$$
\begin{matrix}0&\longrightarrow&\mathbb{R}&\longrightarrow&\mathfrak{h_1}&\longrightarrow&\mathbb{R}^2&\longrightarrow&0\\ =\downarrow&&=\downarrow&&\varphi_r\downarrow&&=\downarrow&&=\downarrow\\ 0&\longrightarrow&\mathbb{R}&\longrightarrow&\mathfrak{h}_1^r&\longrightarrow&\mathbb{R}^2&\longrightarrow&0\end{matrix}
$$